# `moment.updateLocale` all from 24h to 12h and vice versa

Tags: momentjs

I am using momentjs on my device. Even though locale is en_US for instance, the device settings might say to use 24h format.

I was hoping to set default locale to use 24h so that any of the moment format's that give 12h should give 24h (or vice versa). For instance

- `moment.format('LT')` gives `"8:30 PM"`
- `moment.format('LLLL')` gives `"Thursday, September 4, 1986 8:30 PM"`
- etc

so any of the format's that give 24h should now give it in 12h. I know I can easily use format with the upper case `H` and `HH` however I don't know if the current locale's `LT` or `LLLL` etc include AM/PM. Is there anyway to `moment.updateLocale` all `h` to `H` and `hh` to `HH`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`localeData()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/locale-data/) and `longDateFormat()` to get localized format tokens and discover if the given locale uses `h` (12h) or `H` (24h).

Then you can easily change (e.g. RegExp replace) the localized tokens for `LTS` and `LLLL` using [`updateLocale`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/long-date-formats/).

You can suppress AM/PM display using [`meridiem`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/am-pm/) key inside `updateLocale` or removing `a`/`A` tokens in the localized formats.

Here a live example:

```js
['af' , 'ar-dz', 'ar-kw', 'ar-ly', 'ar-ma', 'ar-sa', 'ar-tn', 'ar', 'az', 'be', 'bg', 'bn', 'bo', 'br', 'bs', 'ca', 'cs', 'cv', 'cy', 'da', 'de-at', 'de-ch', 'de', 'dv', 'el', 'en-au', 'en-ca', 'en-gb', 'en-ie', 'en-nz', 'eo', 'es-do', 'es', 'et', 'eu', 'fa', 'fi', 'fo', 'fr-ca', 'fr-ch', 'fr', 'fy', 'gd', 'gl', 'gom-latn', 'he', 'hi', 'hr', 'hu', 'hy-am', 'id', 'is', 'it', 'ja', 'jv', 'ka', 'kk', 'km', 'kn', 'ko', 'ky', 'lb', 'lo', 'lt', 'lv', 'me', 'mi', 'mk', 'ml', 'mr', 'ms-my', 'ms', 'my', 'nb', 'ne', 'nl-be', 'nl', 'nn', 'pa-in', 'pl', 'pt-br', 'pt', 'ro', 'ru', 'sd', 'se', 'si', 'sk', 'sl', 'sq', 'sr-cyrl', 'sr', 'ss', 'sv', 'sw', 'ta', 'te', 'tet', 'th', 'tl-ph', 'tlh', 'tr', 'tzl', 'tzm-latn', 'tzm', 'uk', 'ur', 'uz-latn', 'uz', 'vi', 'x-pseudo', 'yo', 'zh-cn', 'zh-hk', 'zh-tw'].forEach(localeName => {
  // Get locale data
  let localeData = moment.localeData(localeName);
  // Get localized format tokens for LT and LTS
  let lt = localeData.longDateFormat('LT');
  let llll = localeData.longDateFormat('LLLL');
  // Replace 12h with 24h
  lt = lt.replace(/h/g, 'H');
  llll = llll.replace(/h/g, 'H');

  // Update locale with new values, supperssing am/pm output
  moment.updateLocale(localeName, {
    meridiem : (hour, minute, isLowercase) => '',
    longDateFormat : {
      LT: lt,
      LLLL: llll
    }
  });
  
  const m = moment({h: 15}).locale(localeName);
  console.log(localeName, m.format('LT'), m.format('LLLL'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this @Vincenzo. I shared below the solution I was using. I will combine that solution with your meridiem suppression. My solution below iterates through all `longDateFormat`s with `Object.entries` and does a `.replace`.

Comment: Your solution is very good too! My primary goal was to highlight that you could use `localeData`, `longDateFormat` and `meridiem`, I'm glad it helped.

Comment: Thanks very much for your positive comment on my solution. :) The `meridiem` trick you shared is way way awesome. I wish there was a way to provide 12h and 24h locale data. Because some 12h have a leading 0 for the hour, so my solution had to try to figure that out. I need to include your suppress meridiem trick in there otherwise my solution needs the nasty thing of monkey patching `format` to suppress meridiem.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was using, it doesn't use the meridiem suppression technique from @Vincenzo above, it simply replaces the meridiem. It makes an effort to revert between 12h and 24h, deteciting if it was `hh` before or just `h`. And even if captial `A` or lower `a`.

```
const leading12hZero = {};
const lowerMeridiemPlaceholder = ' '.repeat(3);
const upperMeridiemPlaceholder = ' '.repeat(6);
export function updateTimeFormat(to24h) {
    // to24h - true to set to 24h ELSE false to set to 12h
    const { _abbr, _longDateFormat } = moment.localeData();

    let longDateFormat;
    if (to24h) {
        // set to 24h format
        longDateFormat = Object.entries(_longDateFormat).reduce((formatz, [token, format]) => {
            if (!(token in leading12hZero)) {
                if (format.includes('hh:')) {
                    leading12hZero[token] = true;
                } else {
                    leading12hZero[token] = false;
                }
            }
            formatz[token] = format.replace('hh:', 'HH:').replace('h:', 'HH:').replace('a', `[${lowerMeridiemPlaceholder}]`).replace('A', `[${upperMeridiemPlaceholder}]`);
            return formatz;
        }, {});
    } else {
        // set to 12h format
        longDateFormat = Object.entries(_longDateFormat).reduce((formatz, [token, format]) => {
            const shouldLeadingZero = leading12hZero[token];
            formatz[token] = format.replace('HH:', shouldLeadingZero ? 'hh:' : 'h:').replace('H:', shouldLeadingZero ? 'hh:' : 'h:').replace(`[${lowerMeridiemPlaceholder}]`, 'a').replace(`[${upperMeridiemPlaceholder}]`, 'A');
            return formatz;
        }, {});
    }

    moment.updateLocale(_abbr, { longDateFormat });
}

moment.prototype._formatOriginal = moment.prototype.format;
moment.prototype.format = function(str) {
    return moment.prototype._formatOriginal.call(this, str).replace(lowerMeridiemPlaceholder, '').replace(`${lowerMeridiemPlaceholder} `, '').replace(upperMeridiemPlaceholder, '').replace(`${upperMeridiemPlaceholder} `, '');
}
```